# Post a json using swift

Tags: json, swift, post, http-post

I want to post a json to the server. The json looks like this

```
{
   "user": {
       "email": "email",
       "password": "pass"
   }
}
```

This is what I have got so far, it is not working. I have problem of how to create a json object and how to post it. Thank you in advance.

```
    let myUrl = NSURL(string:"https://dev.jaloo.us/api/sessions.json")
    let postString:NSString = "email=\(username)&password =\(password)"
    let postData:NSData = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest (URL:myUrl!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = postData
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &responseError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create data from your parameter object using NSJSONSerialization, and you will be able to do it like the way you want.

```
let postObject = [
    "user": [
        "email": "email",
        "password": "password"
    ]
]

let data = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(postObject, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
let request = NSMutableURLRequest (URL:myUrl!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = data
```

Comment: let data = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(postObject, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)         this line seems have some problems.

Comment: @user3822508 what problems?

Comment: @user3822508 ah. try! is swift 2 so if you arent using swift 2 it wouldnt work

Comment: @WillM. Yeah, I guess that is the reason. Thank you for helping!